# SSMS Flat File Import messes up flat column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to create a table using the Import Flat File option in SQL Server Management Studio.

The csv file comes from an ETL pipeline in Python where I can choose which decimal separator to use when loading the transformed data into CSV. Thing is, when using the Import Flat File option, whether I chose ',' or '.', the float columns are wrongly imported:

When I preview the data in the PREVIEW step of the SSMS Import Flat file, float values look ok:

158.169769

When I advance to the Modify Columns step, it looks ok too: "float"

But after the import, when I do a select of a float column, it is wrong:

1,58169767398605E+15

Any idea how can I fix this?

**EDIT 1:** Tried to use decimal instead of float in the "Modify column" step of SSMS Import Flat File window, it threw this error:

> Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error inserting data into table.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.SDS)
>
> ---
>
> The given value of type Decimal from the data source cannot be
> converted to type decimal of the specified target column.
> (System.Data)
>
> ---
>
> The given value of type Decimal from the data source cannot be
> converted to type decimal of the specified target column.
> (System.Data)
>
> ---
>
> Parameter value '136658680.0000000000' is out of range.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I would be *very* surprised if the value `158.169769` gets inserted as the value `8,35552064569344E+15`.

Comment: I pasted the correct value, thanks, @Larnu, any Idea why this is happening? :)

Comment: Honestly, none. `158.169769` is nothing like `1,58169767398605E+15`. Even *if* the decimal point were ignored, that would be `1.581698E+08`; you are getting a value that is 10 million times larger. I feel there is something you aren't telling us here.

Comment: I know, thats why I posted the pics, In my notebook the values OK, if I save the pandas dataframe to Excel, the values are OK:

RESOLUTION_TIME_DAYS
158.1697685
35.85148148

After importing the csv to Excel, values are OK as well. The ONLY problem I get is whenever I try to create a table with the SSMS Import Flat File option.

Comment: Float is an approximate datatype, you should (almost always) use decimal

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HoneyBadger, but I tried to use it before posting the answer, let me edit the post with the error it throws (basically, its like Larnu said, SSMS is reading numbers like if they were huge (i.e E+15)

Comment: Your decimal separator is treated as a 1000 separator, in other words ignored. You get this with both a comma and a decimal point as separator? Do you have them both in the file? Regardless of the error, decimal is the right choice (with the correct precision ans scale) if the values are interpreted correctly

Comment: I get this error with both, yep. My file has not them mixed up, I can choose one or other. But it doesn't work.